# Pair of binary stars orbiting each other

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, binary-stars

Suppose we have a pair of binary stars orbiting around each other in their mutual gravitational field. My question is, is the trajectory of the combined system would be an ellipse?
And, if it is an ellipse then what are the conditions required to have so?

Comment: What do you mean by "trajectory of the combined system"? Each star follows its own trajectory.

Comment: The trajectory of the system as seen by observer who is not the part of the system.

Comment: The barycenter will be on the foci of each object's orbital ellipse.  But the system is not subject to any external forces; hence, the barycenter will have steady motion.

Answer (score 1):

The trajectory of the combined system as seen by an observer who is not part of the system will be defined by Newton's laws. The centre of mass will be unaccelerated unless some force from a third body acts upon it and so will not travel in an ellipse.

Thus the only way for the combined object to follow an elliptical trajectory is if it it is in a triple system and thus orbits the common centre of mass with a third body. Providing the binary and the third body are separated by much more than the separation of the stars in the binary system then this will behave like a pair of widely separated bodies following Keplerian (elliptical) orbits.